# How to create lots of gaussian channel in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How to build K gaussian channel code in matlab ? i mean if $h_1,h_2,...,h_K$ are all gaussian channel,how do i write this code in just one or two line code?I know how to write the code if there is just one gaussian channel

`h=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(1,size(x))+1i*randn(1,size(x)));`

But i think it is stupid to write as

```
h_1=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(1,size(x))+1i*randn(1,size(x))) 
h_2=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(1,size(x))+1i*randn(1,size(x)))...
h_K=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(1,size(x))+1i*randn(1,size(x)))
```

then h=[h_1 h_2 h_3 ...h_k]

Does anyone know the better way to write this code?

Someone told me 
define the matrix

```
h = sqrt(1/2).*(randn(K, size(x)) + 1i.*randn(K, size(x)));
```

Then you can access channel h_i for i=1,2,...,K as

```
h[i,:];
```

but after i copy it,the window told me

Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket in the "h[i,:];",does anyone know how to improve this problem?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark oh that's my mistake,but the window still show me Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket in the "h[i,:];"

Comment: In MATLAB you need to index using round brackets: `h(1,:)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thx,but the window show me another error now Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: When you do what? For `h(i,:)`? Is `i` a positive integer scalar? Note that error messages are quite descriptive. I recommend you take some of [these fantastic courses](https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com) to learn MATLAB basics, rather than asking questions here. It’ll be a lot easier on you.